# Losing functionality on our site in archived versions on Internet Archive?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to test out archived snapshots of our site on the Wayback Machine (this is what cloudflare uses in case things go down).

I'm finding that our login button and menu navigation doesn't work at all on any of these archived versions.

Our login button, for example, relies on a js script to function (main.js in this case). In the archived version, I see it being wrapped in some wombat stuff... like so:

```
var _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____ = function(name) {return (self._wb_wombat && self._wb_wombat.local_init && self._wb_wombat.local_init(name)) || self[name]; };
if (!self.__WB_pmw) { self.__WB_pmw = function(obj) { this.__WB_source = obj; return this; } }
{
  let window = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("window");
  let self = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("self");
  let document = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("document");
  let location = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("location");
  let top = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("top");
  let parent = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("parent");
  let frames = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("frames");
  let opener = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("opener");

import {
    _ as e,
    a as t,
    b as n,
    c as o
} from "./_rollupPluginBabelHelpers-7532a869.js";
import {
    F as i,
    A as a,
    T as r,
    M as s,
    a as l,
    b as c,
    L as d
} from "./events-c1f01054.js";
```

And consequently, am getting syntax errors due to "unexpected tokens" at the import statements, seemingly due to wrapping in the wombat functions.

This seems like a pretty basic issue, but I'm worrying if restoring this functionality on archived versions of our site is even possible? All the login button does is trigger a modal to pop up, let the user enter their details, and then that redirects users on submit to a completely separate site that is not tied to this site in any way (i.e. if this site is down, that has no effect on the other). It's a pretty static web page.. but I'm not yet sure what all boxes to check off to see if it's even possible that we can restore said functionality. I find many event listeners on elements on the page are completely missing.

Comment: Even if it was possible, at least for your login button it would make rather little sense to begin with, I suppose - unless that is not actually a login tied to anything server-side on your end (but just client-side authentication using an external login provider such as Facebook, Google) ...? Because if it needs to communicate with your server - then either the WbM will have rewritten whatever URL it needs to send data to as well (and against a _static_ snapshot of your URL, you won't be able to perform a login) - or it will still target your live site, which is currently down.

Comment: @CBroe I meant to add, important info: this login button redirects to a site hosted elsewhere entirely. So if the site where the login button is located is down, that has nothing to do with the site a member is actually trying to access. The event handlers of this login button seem to be stripped entirely. It should make a modal pop up that contains the login form, but even that is not happening.

Comment: ...Huh. TIL. Cloudflare really IS using the Wayback Machine to power its **Always Online** service. Wow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the WbM team. They've logged this as a bug on their end. This isn't so much an answer as much as the question can be closed. Ultimately, it's in their hands now.